# Php: remove (different cases) duplicates from array

Tags: php, arrays

probably an already discussed topic, but in Php I did not found an answer
Is there a simpler way to realize in what follows:

```
$a = array("hello","hello","Hello","world","worlD");
$p=array();
foreach( $a as $v ){
    $p[strtolower($v)] = "";
}
print_r($p);
```

keep one single element, in small-case, for the array

Comment: Use a conditional statement or something like what Yoshi just answered.

Comment: @sephoy he wants to remove duplicates from his array.

Comment: @dynamic: i see, so yoshi's answer can do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like:

```
$p = array_unique(array_map('strtolower', $a));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_flip` to swap keys and values:

```
$a = array_flip(array_map('strtolower', $a));
```